# Change a label in a multiple value parameter in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to change a label under certain circumstances for a multi-value parameter.  A stored procedure is the source for the values in the dataset that is used for the parameter.  For example the parameter gets:

```
ID    |  NAME
-----------------
1     |  Name 1

2     |  Name 2

3     |  Name 3
```

I'm mapping ID to the value and NAME to the label.  I want "Name 2" to display as "Name Two" in the drop down but all others to keep the value fed in from the query.  I can use an expression in the report like

`=IIF(Parameters!PARAM.Label = "Name 2", "Name Two", Parameters!PARAM.Label)`

but is there any way to do this same thing to the parameter label so it gets modified before being displayed?  I know I could massage this in the query so it comes into the report as I want but I am hoping I can handle this in report builder.

I am using Report Builder 3.0 with SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the SSRS report renderer does not allow the parameter values to be determined via formula in properties.  It probably has something to do with the order of when the form renders versus pulling the dataset.

Sorry for the bad news.  It looks like you will have to accomplish this via the actual query feeding the parameter set.